# Who is the woman appearing for less than half a second at the beginning of Die Hard 4?

Tags: live-free-or-die-hard

I was watching [Live Free or Die Hard](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337978/) and I noticed that in the scene where the van drives away after the first hacker was killed, right after, there is a sort of glitch that is used through the beginning of the film. But after the one at 2:20 I thought I saw a woman. It happened so fast that I wasn't sure but then I returned to 2:18 and started clicking play/pause fast enough to see every frame, and that's when I saw her very clearly:

[image: women from Die Hard 4]

It freaked the hell out of me. I searched in Google to see if anyone else saw her but apparently no one did so. Who is she? Why is she in the movie? And why are they showing her so fast and briefly? She looks a bit like Kate Beckinsale.

To see her it is better to open the movie in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and slow it down as much as possible (but start somewhere near 2:17 because it would take forever to get there).

Comment: Holy *Fight Club* Batman ...

Comment: @Paulster2 Well, I for myself would prefer *Kate Beckinsale* to *Tyler Durden* (or the penises he cuts into other movies) anytime.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, [this guy](http://checkingonmysausages.blogspot.com/2009_11_01_archive.html) noticed it at checkingonmysausages, and [this German site](http://erdbeeremiau.blogspot.com/2013/02/abgebildet-quickie-kate-beckinsale-in.html) seems to agree that it is Kate Beckinsale. And it has a mention in [imdb trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337978/trivia) for the movie:
"A single frame shot of director Len Wiseman's wife Kate Beckinsale is spliced into the opening credits, when the van is outside the exploding house.  Beckinsale is married to director Len Wiseman."

Comment: Wow, now that is an interresting find (and a really cool way to pay tribute to your wife).

Comment: It's kind of a creepy way to pay tribute to your wife.

Comment: WHY do you need to pay tribute to your wife?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Apart from it being cool, maybe so that someone notices and then people talk more about your movie (like we are now), thus creating additional publicity.